# Cant use this GPO combination User is member of Group X AND User IS NOT Y

Tags: group-policy, gpo

I'm trying to figure out following GPO issue:

Some weeks ago i had to create a GPO for a rather big Security Group (in this case im calling this Security Group X). They needed a specific Website on their own Desktop.

So i created the GPO with the following item-level target:

```
User is a Member of the Security Group DOMAIN\X
```

Everything worked fine.

Today i received a Ticket in which some Users (which are in the Security Group X) should not receive the specific Website on their Desktop. So i need to delete the Link on their Desktop.

I tried the following item-level targeting:

```
User is a member of the Security Group DOMAIN\X
AND User is not DOMAIN\User1 
AND User is not DOMAIN\User2
AND User is not DOMAIN\User3
```

I also tried it with only "User1".
This doesn't seem to work out for me.

Is this logically even possible?

I'm looking forward for any help.

Thanks!

Comment: `User is not DOMAIN\User1` appears to be complete non-sense.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for pointing this out, i thought of something completly different by using the "User is not" Item.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. Im not quite sure if this is the most beautiful one, but it works.
I placed all Users which should not receive the Website into the Security Group Y.

```
User is a member of the Security Group DOMAIN\X
AND User is NOT a member of the Security Group DOMAIN\Y
```

To make this work I had to delete the Links from their desktops before they got back into the RDP Session.